# inserting text into a Swing textarea on a Quartz Schedule

Tags: java, swing, quartz-scheduler, jtextarea

I'm a bit of a noob and can't figure this out. I've created a method of my GUI class which inserts text into the text area:

```
 public void setMyTextArea(String s) {
         this.myTextArea.insert(s,0);
 }
```

Next I wanted to schedule a job with quartz scheduler, but I wanted to display certain data to my text area. However in my job I have no instance of my Gui so I can't use the above method since it isn't a static method. I can't make it static because `myTextArea` is a field that can't be static.

How do I pass an instance of my Gui to the Job? For example, I'm currently passing data with `.usingJobData` but I only see options for passing Booleans, Floats, Integers, Strings, Doubles, i.e. standard types. Am I missing something? Can I pass an Object with `.usingJobData`?

My plan is to pass the Gui instance to the Job and then have the instance use the method `setMyTextArea();` If this isn't the proper way to do it, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Never used Quartz Scheduler before, though, won't this line is what you looking for `scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);`, taken from the Documentation page [Quick Start](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/quick-start), if you scroll to the very bottom of the said page ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose your GUI (e.g. `JFrame` instance) is created and visible. You can use
`java.awt.Window` method

```
public static Window[] getWindows()
```

To get full list of created windows. Iterate through the list and find desired one. Then pass it to the Job.

Comment: this works. Thank you! Any difference between this and `getFrames()`?

Comment: No big difference in fact. I used more common method because I didn't know your GUI class it could extend e.g. Window

Answer (score 1):

There is no `usingJobData` method that will take an object reference.

Instead you will need to populate a `JobDataMap` yourself using with `put(String key, Object value)`

Then you can set this `Map` with the `usingJobData(JobDataMap newJobDataMap)` on your `JobBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

> is a field that can't be static.

eghm...actially it can be static field, why not?

btw: all updates on gui must be done in EDT thread, use SwingUtilities.invokeLater to perform changes on gui from another threads

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The job can be passed any object to use at the runtime of job.

> Can I pass an Object with .usingJobData?

The JobDataMap can accept values of type "Object".
So, you can always create a map , put some required values in it and pass it to your job.